# Gremlin query overlapping datetimes

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I have the following graph database.
[Link to graph image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BLkK3vofM6-E2rOp3sNR2LpKVVRdbMsR)

Here is the script to load the data

```
//Use case for datetimes working at the same company
//only for tinkerpop
graph=TinkerGraph.open()
g=graph.traversal()
//from here on common between neptune and tinkerpop

//Setup started
//create vertexes

//create a company Coca Cola
g.addV('company').property(id,'c1')
g.V('c1').property('name','Coca Cola')
g.V('c1').property('questId','10')

//create a person Alice
g.addV('person').property(id,'p1')
g.V('p1').property('questId','1')
g.V('p1').property('name','Alice')


//create a person Bob
g.addV('person').property(id,'p2')
g.V('p2').property('questId','2')
g.V('p2').property('name','Bob')


//create a person Chris
g.addV('person').property(id,'p3')
g.V('p3').property('questId','3')
g.V('p3').property('name','Chris')


//create a person David
g.addV('person').property(id,'p4')
g.V('p4').property('questId','4')
g.V('p4').property('name','David')

//create a person Emma
g.addV('person').property(id,'p5')
g.V('p5').property('questId','5')
g.V('p5').property('name','Emma')

//create edges
//Coca Cola employes Alice
g.addE('employeed').from(g.V('c1')).to(g.V('p1')).property(id,'c1p1')
g.E('c1p1').property('fromDate','2009-01-10').next()
g.E('c1p1').property('toDate','2018-12-13').next()

//create edges
//Coca Cola employes Bob
g.addE('employeed').from(g.V('c1')).to(g.V('p2')).property(id,'c1p2')
g.E('c1p2').property('fromDate','2015-11-13').next()

//create edges
//Coca Cola employes Chris
g.addE('employeed').from(g.V('c1')).to(g.V('p3')).property(id,'c1p3')
g.E('c1p3').property('fromDate','2017-01-10').next()
g.E('c1p3').property('toDate','2019-01-10').next()

//create edges
//Coca Cola employes Chris
g.addE('employeed').from(g.V('c1')).to(g.V('p4')).property(id,'c1p4')
g.E('c1p4').property('fromDate','2008-01-10').next()
g.E('c1p4').property('toDate','2016-01-10').next()

//create edges
//Coca Cola employes Emma
g.addE('employeed').from(g.V('c1')).to(g.V('p5')).property(id,'c1p5')
g.E('c1p5').property('fromDate','2016-01-01').next()
```

Am i wondering where is possible to run the following queries?

1. We need to know who can we ask for a reference for Alice.
2. A reference can be given only by somebody that has worked with Alice in the same company for a given amount of time of overlap.
3. Their last job together should have happened a maximum amount of time ago from today
4. The amount of time of overlap is an input in the query.
5. The amount of time ago from today is an input to the query.

The results should be

Amount of time of overlap   Amount of time ago (From today) Result
3 Years Overlap --- 2 Years working together -- Bob – Employeed - Coca Cola

The only thing I was able to come up with was the following query which is far from requirements.

```
//People who worked between dates with Alice
g.V().hasLabel('person').
       repeat(bothE().has('fromDate',between('2009-01-01','2020-12-31')).otherV().simplePath()).
       until(has('name','Alice')).
       path().
       by('name').
       by(label)

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbKUV.jpg
```

Comment: Your question is not complete and is missing vital details. Hence it cannot be answered.

Comment: Is it completed now? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: With dates stored as Strings you can't really make any computations unless you use some lambdas. So my first suggestion would be to change the date properties to Longs or Integers (epoch days).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the final queries to achieve my use cases.

First Use case. 
Amount of time of overlap 3 YEARS
Amount of time ago (From today) 2 YEARS 
Result  Bob – Employeed - Coca Cola

Query

```
g.V().has('person','name','Alice').
  inE('employeed').as('e1').outV().
  outE('employeed').
  where(neq('e1')).as('e2').
  and(values('fromDate').is(lt(17948))).
  and(values('toDate').is(gt(17215))).
  inV().
  project('colleague','start','end').
        by('name').
        by(union(select('e2').values('fromDate'),select('e1').values('fromDate')).max()).
        by(union(select('e2').values('toDate'),select('e1').values('toDate')).min()).
  filter(math('end-start').is(gte(1095))).
  select('colleague','start','end')
```

Result

==>[colleague:Bob,start:16751,end:17877]

Answer (score 0):

With dates as Integers you could do something like this:

```
today = LocalDate.now()
start = today.minusYears(3)
minOverlap = 365 * 2 // 2 years

g.V().has('person','name','Alice').
  inE('employeed').as('e1').outV().
  outE('employeed').where(neq('e1')).as('e2').inV().
  project('colleague','start','end').
    by('name').
    by(union(select('e1','e2').select(values).unfold().values('fromDate'),
             constant(start.toEpochDay())).max()).
    by(union(coalesce(select('e1').values('toDate'), constant(today.toEpochDay())),
             coalesce(select('e2').values('toDate'), constant(today.toEpochDay()))).min()).
  filter(math('end-start').is(gte(minOverlap))).
  select('colleague')
```

This will return `Bob` and `Emma`; both of them worked with `Alice` for about 3 years.

Comment: Thanks for your help. here is the modified version using days from epoch. See the updated version on top. still can´t get the right people.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved version of data ingestion using days from epoch. 
Script to load data but doesn´t seem to work.

```
        //Use case for datetimes working at the same company
    //only for tinkerpop
    graph=TinkerGraph.open()
    g=graph.traversal()
    //from here on common between neptune and tinkerpop//Setup started
    //create vertexes//create a company Coca Cola
    g.addV('company').property(id,'c1')
    g.V('c1').property('name','Coca Cola')
    g.V('c1').property('questId','10')//create a person Alice
    g.addV('person').property(id,'p1')
    g.V('p1').property('questId','1')
    g.V('p1').property('name','Alice')
    //create a person Bob
    g.addV('person').property(id,'p2')
    g.V('p2').property('questId','2')
    g.V('p2').property('name','Bob')
    //create a person Chris
    g.addV('person').property(id,'p3')
    g.V('p3').property('questId','3')
    g.V('p3').property('name','Chris')
    //create a person David
    g.addV('person').property(id,'p4')
    g.V('p4').property('questId','4')
    g.V('p4').property('name','David')//create a person Emma
    g.addV('person').property(id,'p5')
    g.V('p5').property('questId','5')
    g.V('p5').property('name','Emma')//create edges
    //Coca Cola employes Alice
    g.addE('employeed').from(g.V('c1')).to(g.V('p1')).property(id,'c1p1')
    g.E('c1p1').property('fromDate',14253).next()
    g.E('c1p1').property('toDate',17877).next()//create edges
    //Coca Cola employes Bob
    g.addE('employeed').from(g.V('c1')).to(g.V('p2')).property(id,'c1p2')
    g.E('c1p2').property('fromDate',16751).next()//create edges
    //Coca Cola employes Chris
    g.addE('employeed').from(g.V('c1')).to(g.V('p3')).property(id,'c1p3')
    g.E('c1p3').property('fromDate',17175).next()
    g.E('c1p3').property('toDate',17905).next()//create edges
    //Coca Cola employes Chris
    g.addE('employeed').from(g.V('c1')).to(g.V('p4')).property(id,'c1p4')
    g.E('c1p4').property('fromDate',13887).next()
    g.E('c1p4').property('toDate',16809).next()//create edges
    //Coca Cola employes Emma
    g.addE('employeed').from(g.V('c1')).to(g.V('p5')).property(id,'c1p5')
    g.E('c1p5').property('fromDate',16809).next()
```

Here the query to get people working in the last two years for an overlap of 1 year. I should get only Bob.

```
//Neptune
g.V().has('person','name','Alice').
  inE('employeed').as('e1').outV().
  outE('employeed').where(neq('e1')).as('e2').inV().
  project('colleague','start','end').
    by('name').
    by(union(select('e1','e2').select(values).unfold().values('fromDate'),
             constant(16877)).max()).
    by(union(coalesce(select('e1').values('toDate'), constant(17972)),
             coalesce(select('e2').values('toDate'), constant(17972))).min()).
  filter(math('end-start').is(gte(365))).
  select('colleague')
```

Comment: Why only Bob? In the last 2 years (starting: 2017-02-20), Alice worked for at least 1 year with Bob (2017-02-20 to 2018-12-13), Chris (2017-02-20 to 2018-12-13) and Emma (2017-02-20 to 2018-12-13).